# Travis.yml file not being found in Django project

Tags: python, django, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I have a Django project that needs to be built using TravisCI. Originally, I put the travis.yml file in the root of the project (where the virtual environment would be) and then built it but for some reason, Travis is using default settings since it can't find the yml file.

I then moved the file into the src directory and rerun, but the build still wasn't finding the file. **Where does the file need to be placed in order for Travis to find it?**

**Travis.yml**:

```
language: python
python:
- "2.7"
# setup environment
env:
- DJANGO_VERSION=1.11.2
- DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='di_photouploader.settings.production'
# install dependencies
install:
- pip install -r requirements.txt

# run test scripts
script:
- python manage.py test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be named

```
.travis.yml
```

And not

```
Travis.yml
```

Place the file at the project root.